# CoordinatorLayout with NestedScroll and CollapsingToolbarLayout doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: android, material-design, nestedscrollview

I am having an issue with `CoordinatorLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`,  the toolbar is working fin, but when I scroll the activity to bottom, it does never get to the bottom it only gets until the 2nd row before the last one.

Is there any problem in my xml? (I am loading the text from strings.xml programmatically)

This is my Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img_1"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/par_toolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:text="@string/app_toolbar_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/Blanco"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        android:paddingRight="32dp"
        android:paddingLeft="32dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="32dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/background"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_paragraph_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_paragraph"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="@string/history1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that behavior you have described is caused by layout_gravity attribute of your NestedScrollView. Try to remove it.